# How to record this value in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a data that looks like this

```
"discountPrices": [
    {
      "startQuantity": 3,
      "price": 65.0
    },
    {
      "startQuantity": 8,
      "price": 62.0
    },

   {
      "startQuantity": 20,
      "price": 60.0
    },

  ]
```

As you know, this is a discount price of a product. I am trying to achieve two things here.

1.) I want to create a table called discountprice and the table will have columns namely price | minqty | maxqty. Using the data above, the first row will be 65.00 | 3 | 7 , and the second row will be 62.00 | 8 | 19 and the third row will be 60 | 20 | 1000.
The issue I am first here is that I don't know how to get the maximum qty because the data did not contain the maximum quantity. It only states the startQuantity. How can I get the Maxquanity for each of the row and record it?

2.) How can I output it on a page. For example, using the data, I can do something like 3>=7 = $65.00, 8>=19 = $62.00 , 20>=1000 = $60.00

I think the hardest part is how to know the maximum quantity since it is not specified. Please how can I achieve this result.

Comment: What do you mean by "because the data did not contain the maximum quantity". If the data you have doesn't include it, you have to get it from whoever supplies the data. But I think you mean something else, please specify. Is there a database table where the maximum quantity might be?

Comment: It is an api data. The maximum was not specified. You can only know the maximum of the first after you have seen the minimum of the second data. For example, if you look at the array, the minimum of the second data is 8, this means that the maximum of the first one will be 7

Comment: I'm sorry I still have difficulties understanding. What if the start quantity is 20, is the maximum of the previous data 19 then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code snnipt to get the max quantity

```
$json = '[  
 {  
  "startQuantity":3,
  "price":65.0
 },
 {  
  "startQuantity":8,
  "price":62.0
 },
 {  
  "startQuantity":20,
  "price":60.0
 }
]';

$jsonToArray = json_decode($json, true);
$startQuantity = array_column($jsonToArray, 'startQuantity');
array_walk($jsonToArray, function($v, $k) use (&$jsonToArray, $startQuantity) {
    $index = array_search($v['startQuantity'], $startQuantity);
    if(array_key_exists($index+1, $startQuantity))
         $jsonToArray[$k]['endQuantity']  = $startQuantity[$index+1]-1;
});
print_r($jsonToArray);
```

Result

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [startQuantity] => 3
        [price] => 65
        [endQuantity] => 7
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [startQuantity] => 8
        [price] => 62
        [endQuantity] => 19
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [startQuantity] => 20
        [price] => 60
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the max qty. Just store your data as is and query for the first row that has a startQuantity less than or equal to your orderQuantity:

```
SELECT price FROM discounts
    WHERE startQuantity <= :orderQuantity
    ORDER BY startQuantity DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bf111/15) for example.

If you don't find a result, then there's no discount and your price is just the base undiscounted price. (Or you could insert a row with the base price and 0 for startQuantity.)

Note, I assume you're selling more than one product, so you'll likely need a field in that table (and the associated WHERE clause) to identify which product.